# I keep getting this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

This one is making me sick.because i cant find where i am going wrong.I will
appreciate any help or hint from you. below is my javascript code.so far the server side is fine but display the actual comment on the client side is the problem. please help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // process the form
    $('form.comments_form').each(function () {
        var form_to_submit = $(this);
        form_to_submit.submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var posta_id = form_to_submit.find("input[type=hidden].UNIQUE_ID").val();
            var tetxarea1 = form_to_submit.find("textarea.target").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url: 'http://localhost/Forepost/php/real_time_comment.php', // the url where we want to POST
                data: {
                    posta_id: posta_id,
                    tetxarea1: tetxarea1
                }, // our data object
                dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                success: (function (response) {
                    display_the_comment(jQuery.parseJSON(response));
                    console.log(response);
                }),
                error: function () {
                    alert("oops something went wrong");
                    // oops something went wrong
                }
            });

            //FUNCTION TO DISPLAY COMMENT FROM DATABASE
            function display_the_comment(response) {
                var comment_string = " ";
                comment_string += "<li class='indiv_cmnts'>";
                comment_string += "<span class='user_fname2'>'" + response.f_name + "'</span>";
                comment_string += "<div class='my_msg'>'" + esponse.my_comment + "'</div>";
                comment_string += "<img class='user_proff' src='" + response.profile_img + "'/>";
                comment_string += "<span class='time_cmnts'>'" + response.my_comment_date + "'</span>";
                //comment_string += "<span class='fa_reply'><i class='fa fa-reply' aria-hidden='true'></i> reply</span>";
                comment_string += "</li>";

                $("ul.comenting2").prepend(comment_string);
            }
            //FUNCTION TO DISPLAY COMMENT FROM DATABASE
        });
    });
});
```

i am trying to display the list to unordered lis with the class "comenting2"

Comment: What's the JSON data you're getting back? I've had this issue recently and it's due to illegal characters being sent in the JSON response.

Comment: Can you please try to get that JSON response string or data which you used for parsing? This will help to find out problem. I mean we need data of "response" which you parse using jQuery.parseJSON

Comment: You don't need to use JSON.parse, since you already told jquery you expect json data back it is automatically parsed and you get a response object. Run console.log(response) without parsing beforehand to see what I mean.

Comment: $my_comment = $rowR['comments'];
        $my_comment_date = $rowR['date_time_commented'];
        $time = date("d-M-Y", strtotime( $my_comment_date));
        
        $std= new stdClass();
        $std->f_name=$f_name;
        $std->l_name=$l_name;
        $std->my_comment=$my_comment;
        $std->my_comment_date=$my_comment_date;
        $std->profile_img='http://localhost/Forepost/icons/forepost_user.png';
        echo json_encode($std);

Comment: ok that is the data i have prepared from my php

Answer (score 0):

change your code from
 `$("ul.comenting2").prepend(comment_string);`
to
  `$("ul.comenting2").prepend($(comment_string));`

Comment: Object { f_name: "said", l_name: "jillo", my_comment: "rrtr", my_comment_date: "2017-03-10 10:30:29.000000", profile_img: "http://localhost/Forepost/icons/for…" }

Comment: i get that response

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To make it easier to understand the problem. I believe it would be great if you also supplied the sample of your JSON response. It is usually caused by bad JSON format.

Okay. Got your sample JSON response.
Try to change your code into:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: 'http://localhost/Forepost/php/real_time_comment.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data: {
                posta_id: posta_id,
                tetxarea1: tetxarea1
            }, // our data object
            dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            success: (function (response) {
                display_the_comment(eval('('+response+')'));
                console.log(response);
            }),
            error: function () {
                alert("oops something went wrong");
                // oops something went wrong
            }
        });

        //FUNCTION TO DISPLAY COMMENT FROM DATABASE
        function display_the_comment(response) {
            var comment_string = " ";
            comment_string += "<li class='indiv_cmnts'>";
            comment_string += "<span class='user_fname2'>&lsquo;" + response.f_name + "&rsquo;</span>";
            comment_string += "<div class='my_msg'>&lsquo;" + esponse.my_comment + "&rsquo;</div>";
            comment_string += "<img class='user_proff' src='" + response.profile_img + "'/>";
            comment_string += "<span class='time_cmnts'>&lsquo;" + response.my_comment_date + "&rsquo;</span>";
            //comment_string += "<span class='fa_reply'><i class='fa fa-reply' aria-hidden='true'></i> reply</span>";
            comment_string += "</li>";

            $("ul.comenting2").prepend(comment_string);
        }
```

Please noted the changes at ajax success and function display_the_comment(response)

Answer (score 0):

Your response value already is an object since jquery parses it automatically (you put json as datatype). You are trying to json-parse an object, of course that has illegal characters.